# Is it possible to generate a pytest HTML report on a timeout?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html

I'm using [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) and want to combine two plugins in a graceful way, [`pytest-html`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-html/) and [`pytest-timeout`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-timeout/). I'm operating on Windows, so I have to use the thread-method of timing out from `pytest-timeout`, which causes a full-stop to all testing. I want an html from `pytest-html` to be generated in this instance, but was unsure of the plausibility of this from hierarchy issues with the interrupt.

UPDATE, progress so far:
I've added a function to `conftest.py` that manually generates the html before every test case, with the session data that exists at that point. This is a roundabout method of generating the html before the timeout, as opposed to only at the end of testing, simply because the html is being continuously regenerated throughout the process.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def test_blackbox(request):
    session = request.node
    html = request.config._html
    report_content = html._generate_report(session)
    html._save_report(report_content)
```

I could add similar code to the `timeout_timer` method of `timeout`, which is the function that is called when the timer thread runs out, but I want to avoid directly editing the plugin itself. I'll answer once I complete my original task.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @Nearoo Edited the post to pose the question, thank you

Comment: @mhoffman2016: You should give it a try first and then post if you get any issues. I don't think there should be a problem with what you want to achieve. I have tried `pytest-timeout` with Allure and it works fine.